# Viewbox using symbol differs from viewbox using underlying shape

Tags: javascript, svg, viewbox

I am trying to understand viewBox, using a circle for testing. I have two tests, and for each one I have two ways of testing. The first test uses a viewBox of 0 0 30 30, which should show the top left hand corner of the circle. The second test uses a viewBox of 30 30 30 30, which should show the bottom right hand corner of the circle. If I create the svg circle directly, both tests work as intended. If I place the circle inside a symbol, the first test works, but the second test displays nothing.

```
var NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var xlink = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';

// svg definitions
var svg_defs = document.createElementNS(NS, 'svg');
document.body.appendChild(svg_defs);
svg_defs.style.width = '0px';
svg_defs.style.height = '0px';

// svg circle definition
var circ1 = document.createElementNS(NS, 'circle');
svg_defs.appendChild(circ1);
circ1.id = 'circ1';
circ1.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', 30);
circ1.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', 30);
circ1.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 30);
circ1.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'lightgreen');

// svg symbol definition with circle
var sym = document.createElementNS(NS, 'symbol');
svg_defs.appendChild(sym);
var circ2 = document.createElementNS(NS, 'circle');
sym.appendChild(circ2);
sym.id = 'circ2';
circ2.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', 30);
circ2.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', 30);
circ2.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 30);
circ2.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'lightblue');

// div using viewBox(0 0 30 30)
var div_a = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div_a);

// svg for circle definition
var svg1a = document.createElementNS(NS, 'svg');
div_a.appendChild(svg1a);
svg1a.style.margin = '20px';
svg1a.style.border = '1px solid black';
svg1a.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 30);
svg1a.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 30);
svg1a.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', '0 0 30 30');

// attach circle definition
var u1a = document.createElementNS(NS, 'use');
u1a.setAttributeNS(xlink, 'xlink:href', '#circ1')
svg1a.appendChild(u1a);

// svg for symbol definition
var svg2a = document.createElementNS(NS, 'svg');
div_a.appendChild(svg2a);
svg2a.style.margin = '20px';
svg2a.style.border = '1px solid black';
svg2a.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 30);
svg2a.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 30);
svg2a.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', '0 0 30 30');

// attach symbol definition
var u2a = document.createElementNS(NS, 'use');
u2a.setAttributeNS(xlink, 'xlink:href', '#circ2')
svg2a.appendChild(u2a);

// div using viewBox(30 30 30 30)
var div_b = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div_b);

// svg for circle definition
var svg1b = document.createElementNS(NS, 'svg');
div_b.appendChild(svg1b);
svg1b.style.margin = '20px';
svg1b.style.border = '1px solid black';
svg1b.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 30);
svg1b.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 30);
svg1b.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', '30 30 30 30');

// attach circle definition
var u1b = document.createElementNS(NS, 'use');
u1b.setAttributeNS(xlink, 'xlink:href', '#circ1')
svg1b.appendChild(u1b);

// svg for symbol definition
var svg2b = document.createElementNS(NS, 'svg');
div_b.appendChild(svg2b);
svg2b.style.margin = '20px';
svg2b.style.border = '1px solid black';
svg2b.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 30);
svg2b.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 30);
svg2b.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', '30 30 30 30');

// attach symbol definition
var u2b = document.createElementNS(NS, 'use');
u2b.setAttributeNS(xlink, 'xlink:href', '#circ2')
svg2b.appendChild(u2b);
```

See this JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0scrgh4x/

Comment: Although you did not mention it in your updated answer, your modified version adds width and height to the 'use' element. It turns out that this is all that is required to solve my problem. I would still like to know why this makes a difference.

Comment: Another observation. If I use a 'g' (group) element instead of a 'symbol' the problem does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

I've added `style="overflow:visible"` to the symbol.

```html
<svg style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
<symbol id="circ2"  viewBox="0 0 30 30" style="overflow:visible">
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" fill="lightblue"></circle>  </symbol>
</svg>


 <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="30 30 30 30" style="margin: 20px; border: 1px solid black;">
 <use xlink:href="#circ2"></use>
  
  </svg>
```

#### UPDATE

An alternative solution where the `<symbol>` has a `viewBox="0 0 60 60"`. Since the symbol has the size of the circle there is no need for `style="overflow:visible"`

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60" width="0" >
  <symbol id="circ2" viewBox="0 0 60 60" >
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" fill="lightblue"></circle>
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#circ2" x="0" y="0"></use>
</svg>

<svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" >
 <use xlink:href="#circ2"  width="60" height="60"></use>
</svg>

<svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="30 30 30 30" >
 <use xlink:href="#circ2"  width="60" height="60"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: The right thing to do would be to put the symbol contents inside the symbol. overflow:visible is always going to be a performance killer.